# Javascript not working with Gingerbread Webkit WebView, can I somehow override code?

Tags: android, jquery, webkit

I have a webapp with a webview where the javascript is not compatible with the webkit that ships with Gingerbread. Is there a way to inject/override code without making changes to the site itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
wv.loadUrl("javascript:...");
```

to execute arbitrary JavaScript (here shown as `...`) in the context of the current page of a `WebView` (here referred to as `wv`). Whether you can use that to patch up your problems, I cannot say.